# Can a riddle design guru achieve more experience?

Tags: riddle

You return to your desk at work to find the following objects:

A small cube, a small square, a human hand, a diagram of the A-minor chord, a Twix bar, a toy slot machine, a tool for flat tires, a Lebron James figurine, a Pearl Jam CD, a toy car without wheels, a revolver, a picture of Cincinnati, and a small replica of a football field-goal post.

How are all of these objects related?

Comment: They are all on your desk.

Comment: "a human hand" excuse me while I call HR and/or the police.

Comment: All objects' description starts with "A"

Comment: Awww you guys are cracking me up :)

Comment: Were they all stolen or used in committting a crime? Maybe they are murder weapons.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well if you take

> the first letters of the question's title, you get: **CARD GAME**.

So the objects represent

> each value of a suit of cards from Ace to King.
>
>  A cube has **8** vertices
>  <s>A square has **4** sides</s> A small square = $3^2$ = **9**
>  A hand has **5** fingers
>  An A-minor chord is made of the notes A, C, and E giving **ACE**
>  There are **2** pieces in a Twix bar
>  A toy slot machine has a jackpot of **7**s?
>  A tool for flat tires is a **Jack**
>  Lebron is **King** James
>  Pearl Jam has an album **Ten**
>  A toy car is missing **4** wheels
>  Cincinnati is the **Queen** city
>  A revolver is sometimes called a **6**-shooter
>  A field goal is worth **3** points

Comment: A small cube = 2 ^ 3, a small square = 3 ^ 2?

Comment: This is probably a long shot but "hotwheels" has 9 letters....

Comment: @Neon612 That seems legit, but no idea if it's what OP intended!

Comment: Also a "hot" item is a stolen item. So, the wheels are missing.... Does that mean they are hot?

Comment: @Neon612 I knew they were turning all my childhood toys into blockbuster movies (Transformers, GI Joe, Legos, etc.) but I hadn't realized until just now that the Fast and Furious movies are the same thing for Hotwheels! ;)

Comment: Well done Dan!  For the record, the small square is 9 and the car is 4 for the missing wheels.

Answer (score 1):

How are they related?

> They all represent some sort of number

A small cube - 6

A small square - 4

A human hand - 5

A-minor chord - 3

A Twix bar - 2

Toy Slot Machine - 3

a Tool for Flat Tires - 4

Lebron James - 6

Pearl Jam - 10

Toy car without wheels - 0

Revolver - 6

Cincinnati - 65 (ranking in large cities in US.)

Football field goal - 3

Comment: Close, but not quite.

Comment: Incorrect answers: square, cube, chord, slot machine, tool, LBJ, toy car, Cincinnati.  You're on the right track though.

Comment: Think about the order of the numbers.